# Setting a maximum width at collapsed columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I got a table with collapsing rows exactly like this: [Collapsing table](https://www.bootply.com/GGAMvot45f)

As you see in the example, if the row is expanding the first column is growing unnecessary wider. (It's already too big anyway)

Neither setting a maximum width in percent or in pixel, nor defining the column as "col-2"(bootstrap4) works.

How can i set the width of the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting your fixed width on the th tag of your column :

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 25px">Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Your forked bootply : https://www.bootply.com/ITB1qlMHDW

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks a lot! It could be so easy,i don't know why i didn't tried this simply solution. Maybe it depends on the long working day :)